# Data sharing on a multi-instance application

Tags: architecture, database, multitenancy, instance

I would like to know which architecture is more suitable when considering data sharing between tenants:  a Multi-instance (Single-tenant) or Multi-tenant architecture with a database by tenant.

Imagine this first scenario with two clients who each having an instance of the same application and therefore each have a separate database. A third client also connects to its instance, but in addition, it must be able to read and / or write certain data at client 1 and / or client 2.

What are the possibilities to allow such data sharing in an architecture as described above?

And second scenario, if we have 100 tenants, therefore 100 databases, and if I need global analysis functionality, do I have to query each of these 100 databases to have the complete information?

Comment: There is no general answer as it's a significant factor that depends very much on your situation.  It does sort of sound though in your situation a single instance might be best as you have the requirement to reach between tenants for actual tenants, not just for your own use.  If this were not the case I'd go towards a single DB per tenant (not enough space to elaborate).  You can also consider partitioning by tenant on a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

First a clarification :

- In a [multi-tenant architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy), one instance of an application is shared between several tenants but the data is compartmented so that each tenant only see its own. This can be achieved with [different patterns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns):

  - with a database per tenant
  - with a multi-tenant database
  - with a shared database, the application taking care of the multitenancy by implementing a partitioning scheme
  - any hybridization if the above
- In a single tenant application, each application instance is independent serves a single tenant and uses its own single-tenant database.

Your scenario 1 is somewhat in contradiction with multitenancy because you break the boundaries that the architecture is supposed to ensure: 
* The safest way to handle this is by organizing the connection at application level, as if it were a remote connection with a distant system. It’s like any system interface; you could let the tenants be in control of the interfaces they accept.
* In the case of the shared database you could simplify this kind of connections, because the application could simply read the shared data, implementing the access control rules at application level. It’s in the same time the strength and the weakness of this model.

In your scenario 2: except for the the shared database scenario, you’d have the problem that you would have a lot of (slower) cross tenant queries. If you have to join data of different tenants for example, you’d have to read much more records than if you could let the database do the work.

A proven but expensive approach, if you have a lot of analytics to be done that way, is to create a data warehouse. You’d then load in a shared  database the shared data of the relevant tenants, and make your cross-tenant queries there. A side effect is that the performance overhead generated by the analytical activity would not impact the transactional activity of the tenants.

So whether you use multi-tenant with a database per tenant or multi-instance with single tenant, should not impact significantly your scenarios.